# Which sites have the most female users?

Tags: discussion, statistics

I know, sites like programming and machinery are favoured by men far more than women, so I'm curious to know, which site has most female users (both by number and ratio)?

Comment: This is the Internet, where men are men, and women are men, and children are FBI agents.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stack Overflow does not collect such details on its users.

Have you considered how the information you yourself have provided in your profile would allow a query to tell whether you are male or female?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how they determine male versus female (possibly from affiliate sites that do record it) or how accurate it is but Quantcast show a chart of male versus female demographics. You could look at a few sites yourself to get a general idea, here are a few examples:

https://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com#demographicsCard

https://www.quantcast.com/cooking.stackexchange.com#/demographicsCard

Answer (score 2):

Stackexchange in general and Stackoverflow in particular do not collect such statistics, nor do I think that it would be possible to accurately collect such statistics.

However, there was the Stack Overflow Developer Survey, which had a polling field about gender, so if you want to see the stats about this (subset) of Stack Overflow participants, you can do so [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2016/03/stack-overflow-developer-survey-results/?cb=1).